# Windows Forms ClickOnce app crashes during FileGroup download

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have a WindowsForms application, which is deployed using ClickOnce with Full Trust. It is getting crashed, when we open login form. The login form loads the other non-core application files in the background. Based on the analysis it seems it is crashing before any file group download is completed. We get the Windows OS dialog saying "App has stopped working". Looking at the event viewer I see below detail. Has anyone seen this error and how to resolve it ? Something wrong I am doing ?

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.IHashElementEntry.get_AllData()
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.IHashElementEntry.get_AllData()
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.DependentAssembly..ctor(System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.AssemblyReferenceEntry)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.get_DependentAssemblies()
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.GetPrivateAssembliesInGroup(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.AddDependencies(System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader, System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest, System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest, System.Uri, System.String, System.String)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState, System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest, System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest, System.Uri, System.String, System.String, System.Deployment.Application.IDownloadNotification, System.Deployment.Application.DownloadOptions)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeGroupCore(Boolean, System.Deployment.Application.SyncGroupHelper)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeGroupAsyncWorker(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: It has been a while since I have worked with ClickOnce. Since your login form loads, are you able to wrap the inside of the thread call with a try catch? Examining that exception in detail would give you more information.

Comment: Already tried, it doesn't hit the catch block. The code is calling the asynchronous methods to download file groups.